# File created by method can't be found inside Android device manager

Tags: java, android-studio

My Android app's write method is able to create a .txt file and I can see it inside emulator's `/Android/data/<my package>/files`

But I want to extract him from emulator but I can't see the file inside Android Device Manager `/data/data/<my package>/files`

There's other files there and I've changed permissions using adb shell:

```
chmod 777 /data, /data/data, /data/data/<my package>/files/*
```

and nothing .

This file is a sort of a log that I need to debug my app.

Well there's a lot of data inside it and I can't just output them inside Log, is too much information.

Can anyone give me a hand on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not access those files through the Android Device Monitor. You could try to run this app on a physical device or to move those important log files to the external storage directory. From there you can access them.

Comment: Do you mean inside emulator's SD? =S